# mvc3 helper for binding textboxes to a hidden field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Im creating a helper class to collect a users date of birth. I don't want to use a date picker as I think they are a bit of a pain to use for dob.

I have created this so far

```
public static DateText DateTextFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> ex)
    {
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(
          @"<div class=""date-control"">" +
          @"<input type='text' name='Day' id='Day' maxlength='2'/>" +
          @"<input type='text' name='Month' id='Month' maxlength='2'/>" +
          @"<input type='text' name='Year' id='Year' maxlength='4'/>" +
          @"<span>e.g. DD-MM-YYYY (31-03-1980)</span>" +
          @"<input type='hidden' name='Date' id='Date'/>" +
          @"</div>"

       );

        return new DateText(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
```

I was going to create a script to get the data from the 3 textboxes and populate the hidden field ready for the http post.

So lets say I create my control like

```
    @Html.DateTextFor(model => model.DOB)
```

What do I need to modify in my helper to bind the hidden field to the model so when on postback I have the data I want?

Also when my page renders I am getting 'My.Helpers.DateText' text been added into the page, what is causing this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cliet side, you would use JavaScript and intercept the post, populate the field and continue. Server side alternative would be combining the fields in your viewmodel, DOB read only, or you could also inherit from defaultModelBimder and handle the combining there (seems like overkill). I'm mobile so I apologize for not adding more detail.